# How to convert unconvertable & unviewable .ts files?

Tags: format-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert. Ts files into something useful?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3645/how-do-i-convert-ts-files-into-something-useful)

**How to convert. Ts files that can not be converted with usual WinFF, Avidemux etc programs?**

The. Ts files in question are recorded from TV with **STV digital cable digibox**, viewable to me so far **ONLY** with that same digibox.

All the video-playing programs I tried do not open the files at all (e.g. classical VLC and WinMedia player). All but 1 video converters I tried also are not able even to open or load the file into the program, therefore no conversion is possible. According to WinFF it can not find codec parameters during the conversion, evidently leading to nothing-happening?

Comment: what "STV digital cable digibox" are we talking about? Brand and model please. And I'm afraid it's too localized and offtopic on Ubuntu (as this is not specific for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 12.04, please install [Mediainfo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mediainfo-gui/) and paste the metadata of the file into your question. If I recall correctly WinFF is nothing more than a GUI to FFmpeg. Are you sure the file is not protected by DRM or some other mechanisms?

Usually transport streams captured from TV can contain frame drops or other glitches. If that's the case and you couldn't fix this on Windows with the usual tools like tsRemuxer, things will get messy and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, from the command line,

```
avconv -i input.ts -c copy output.mkv
```

will convert the video unless, as @livewire has suggested, it is protected by DRM.