# Ffmpeg: can TS video be converted directly to MP4 video without re-coding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert, mp4, mkv

I see [here (How to convert .ts file into a mainstream format losslessly?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/716457/925128) that MKV is recommended for that purpose (`ffmpeg -i input -map 0 -c copy output.mkv`), but **not MP4, which is said to involve re-encoding the video**.

(Based on that, I use `sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0 -c copy "${0%%.*}".mkv' %f` in a context menu action as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1209832/925128).)

[Here (How to convert .mkv file into .mp4 file losslessly?)](https://askubuntu.com/a/195346/925128) I see that converting MKV to MP4 without re-encoding is very easy (`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy output.mp4`), by simply changing the container.

### If TS->MKV->MP4 conversion-without-recoding is possible, shouldn't TS->MP4 be possible directly too?

---

I have added  to my file manager context menu  the command `sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0 -c copy "${0%%.*}".mp4' %f` and it works without problems for .ts files just like for .mkv .

Checking with Mediainfo the two resulting MP4 files (the `TS->MP4` and the `TS->MKV->MP4`, where `->` is the aforementioned command) I see basically the same info about their video content.

[image]

The rest is the same:

> Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 /
>   deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x3 / me=dia / subme=3 / psy=1 /
>   psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0
>   / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 /
>   chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=8 / lookahead_threads=2 /
>   sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0
>   / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=0 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0
>   / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 /
>   keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=0 /
>   rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=24.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 /
>   qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=3000 / vbv_bufsize=3000 / crf_max=0.0 /
>   nal_hrd=none / filler=0 / ip_ratio=0.71 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=1:1.00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TS > MP4? It Depends™

**Yes**, TS video be converted (re-muxed) directly to MP4 video without re-encoding **if the video and audio formats are compatible**. Your video is H.264 which is currently the most common and most compatible video format in MP4, so copying it from the TS to the MP4 will be no problem.

## Arbitrary formats

TS supports more formats than MP4. If you try to mux arbitrary formats into MP4 the possible results are:

- **Success** - the formats are supported by the FFmpeg MP4 muxer and your player/device.
- **Partial success** - the formats are supported by the FFmpeg MP4 muxer, but not supported by your player/device. This could be the case for less common or legacy formats supported by MP4.
- **Failure** - the formats are not supported and the muxer will give you an error message such as `Could not find tag for codec foo in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

## Recommended procedure

So for full compatibility I recommend re-encoding if the formats are **not** the common and widely supported H.264 or H.265/HEVC video + AAC audio.

For automation you can use `ffprobe` to determine the formats. See [Is there a way to use ffmpeg to determine the encoding of a file before transcoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35280871/1109017) for an example. Then use an if/then statement in your script to execute the correct command.

## Subtitles

The main exception is subtitles. MP4 doesn't have good subtitle support. If your TS contains text subtitles (ASS/SSA, SRT) then you can convert them to timed text (`-c:s mov_text`), but support for timed text subtitles among players is not universal. Image based subtitles will have to be excluded, such as with [negative mapping](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) `-map 0 -map -0:s`.

Comment: Is it then true that TS->MKV is less problematic or not at all? (In which case a simple way is TS->MKV->MP4?)

Comment: @cipricus No, there is no reason to do TS->MKV->MP4. I'm not sure where this notion originated. You can do TS->MP4 directly as long as the formats are supported.

Comment: That idea (the need for TS->MKV->MP4) was in case TS->MKV **and** MKV->MP4 would have **always** worked. But now I understand that is not the case. When it works, like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/50433/925128)  case, it's because the MKV file there contains h.264 video; I guess what you say about "Arbitrary formats" in TS applies to MKV too (**MKV** supports more formats than MP4). — What about TS->MKV? *Is TS supporting more formats than* ***MKV?***

Comment: Yes, MKV supports more formats than MP4. MKV can handle so many formats that TS->MKV should likely not be problematic, but of course there will always be exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I had >200 .ts files from a DLINK security camera I needed to stitch up losslessly for the authorities (insurance).

First create a list of the ts files to combine:

```
for i in `\ls *.ts | sort -V`; do echo "file '$i'"; done >> mylist.txt;
```

Merge them into one ts:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe "0" -i mylist.txt -c copy merge.ts
```

Then convert the ts directly and losslessly to a well known format for the authorities

```
ffmpeg -i merge.ts -map 0 -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: my exact issue too with .ts files being concatenated together to produce a video.ts file.. had to remove the map because of an error but output from copying the streams was invaluable.

Comment: Glad it worked out without the 'map' option in your case, @DanBradbury!