# Add missing icon to a file-type (extension)?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, video, icons, icon-themes

All the icon packs that I tried were missing the video icon for the video `.ts` files that I have.

I can change 'artificially' the `ts` extension to `mp4` for example to fix this, but I was wandering how could I manually make this type of file show the video icon that is used by other video files like mp4?

Comment: Have you tried to use the MIME type editor in the Settings manager?
Then setting the filetype to Video.

Comment: @KenMollerup - I am not aware of that setting. I use KDE/Kubuntu 16.04. More details much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I'm on Xubuntu and some other XFSE derivatives, Kubuntu (KDE) have an extensive toolbox - have you had a look there?

Comment: @KenMollerup - I was expecting a generic solution, but indeed in KDE it is really simple to fix. I will post that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a desktop-specific issue.

A KDE solution:

Right-click the ts file, Properties/General/Filetype options, then click the icon area and add an icon, namely some video icon.

[image]

[image]

Restart Dolphin and you will see that icon for **all** files with that extension.

Comment: Yea That Works   Happy Ubunting.  ;-)